# Python: is there a way to use "unimported" objects in function definitions?

Tags: python, function, namespaces, python-module

I'm modifying a simple recursive function to draw a dragon curve using turtle:

```
def draw_dragon(t, order, size, L=turtle.left, R=turtle.right):
    """ Draw a dragon curve """
    if not order:
        t.forward(size)
        return

    size /= 1.41421
    t.R(45)
    draw_dragon(t, order-1, size, L, R)
    t.L(90)
    draw_dragon(t, order-1, size, R, L)
    t.R(45)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    fred=turtle.Turtle()
    draw_dragon(fred,6,200)
    wn.exitonclick()
```

Since I haven't yet imported turtle at the time of function definition, the interpreter gives me `"NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined"`.

Is there a way to still use the turtle module's functions in my draw_dragon function, without first importing them outside the function?

Comment: What would be the reason for that? When you define `draw_dragon` you are assigning `turtle.left` to the `L` kwarg; how could the interpreter know what are you trying to assign to `L` if you don't tell it (by an `import` statement or a _definition_). The interpreter parses `turtle.arg` (and it's smart enough to split the offending value by `.` and thus telling you what is the first _submodule_ that wasn't found )

Comment: "Since I haven't yet imported turtle at the time of function definition" - well, why not?

Comment: "Is there a way"? Arguably, with some extremely awful hackery. Is there a _good_ way, compliant with best practices, that won't also break editors' code analysis? No. (And why would you want one, instead of just moving the `import` to the top of the file?)

Comment: I was thinking in case you imported the namespaces at the very beginning and later down the road you might get namespace collisions (you can't 'un-import' a namespace can you?)
Also I thought Python just skips over the function definition and doesn't need the namespace until the point of calling/executing the function...

Comment: You can, actually, but you shouldn't name things the same name as modules you're using.

Comment: @user2357112 - python is _interpreted_;  that means it's executed line by line (there's no compiler to get an idea about the whole thing); + the fact that _the supplied_ code doesn't compile

Comment: @CristiFati: No, I mean why not import turtle at the top of the file, before it's used? Sticking an import in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block that's needed unconditionally is really weird.

Comment: Yes you should have imported `turtle` at the beginning of file (before it's used). Importing something after it's used triggers a paradox. Check [this site]( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). This is mostly for: @user2357112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't importing before the function is defined?
I'm not sure why you would need to put the import in the main function to begin with.

I don't believe there's any magical way for the function to already know what turtle's modules are unless they're either a) in the namespace, or b) passed to the function through the arguments.  You could put this in your main code:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    fred=turtle.Turtle()
    draw_dragon(fred,6,200,turtle.left, turtle.right)
    wn.exitonclick()          ^^^            ^^^
```

Then, change the L and R to not have default arguments (they'll be assigned the functions through the initial call), so you won't get NameErrors.

Your function should now know what the methods are, since you passed them into the function through the main.

You should probably just move the import call to the start of the script, though!

EDIT:

Your code still has some weird idiosyncracies.  Rather than trying to pass methods from imported modules into your functions, just use the functions that are part of the turtle object you created! This code should work, but it is DEFINITELY not the common practice you want to use...

```
def draw_dragon(t, order, size, right, left, forward):
    """ Draw a dragon curve """
    if order <= 0:
        forward(size)
        return

    size /= 1.41421
    right(45)
    draw_dragon(t, order-1, size, right, left, forward)
    left(90)
    draw_dragon(t, order-1, size, left, right, forward)
    right(45)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    fred=turtle.Turtle()
    draw_dragon(fred, 6,200, turtle.left, turtle.right, turtle.forward)
    wn.exitonclick()
```

Better code would be this:

```
from turtle import Screen, left, right, forward, speed, hideturtle

def draw_dragon(order, size, left, right):
    """ Draw a dragon curve """
    if order <= 0:
        forward(size)
        return
    size /= 1.41421
    right(45)
    draw_dragon(order-1, size, right, left)
    left(90)
    draw_dragon(order-1, size, left, right)
    right(45)

if __name__=="__main__":
    speed(0)
    hideturtle()
    wn = Screen()
    draw_dragon(8,200, left, right)
    wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: thanks--I changed the L and R to not have default arguments and passed the turtle functions to draw_dragon. This time I don't get the NameError anymore but instead I get `AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'R'`...Then I got rid of the turtle 't' parameter altogether and the script started to work--why is that?

Comment: "t" is referring to a turtle object.  If you used one of my old edits, R is now "turtle.right"
When you call t.R, you're saying "turtle.turtle.right", which of course isn't a function!
R is already "turtle.right", so you can just do R(angle).

Comment: one last noob question: why do you no longer need the instances of Screen, Turtle, and other setups for the new version to work? (I guess it has to do with the `from xmodule import yfunc`? Thanks again :)

Comment: You still have the instance of Screen (that's where Turtle knows to draw).  I'm not terribly experienced in Turtle, but I believe that Screen is a singleton that Turtle methods (Left, Right, Forward, etc.) know to act on.

The documentation may have more on the specifics of why it works with turtle (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/turtle.html), but in general, it depends on the specific implementation of the methods you import.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem may be due to that your turtle.py is not located at a directory in sys.path.

Comment: I think you're wrong ;) This would result in an `ImportError`, not in a `NameError`. The problem is that since the OP is importing `turtle` _after_ the function's definition (which references `turtle` fo argument's defaults), the name `turtle` doesn't exist when the `def` statement is eval'd.

Comment: I thought I imported turtle BEFORE the function is eval'd...so at the time of evaluating (not defining) the function, shouldn't turtle already be visible?